# How to pass java.io.File from Mule 3 inbound file endpoint

Tags: mule

Using Mule 3, how can I pass a `java.io.File` object payload from an inbound file endpoint to a Groovy script rather than the file's content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn streaming off and override the default message factory on the file connector:

```
<file:connector name="fileConnector" streaming="false" autoDelete="false">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.file.FileMuleMessageFactory" />
</file:connector>
```

Note that it is up to you to move / delete the file either before you start or once you've done processing it, otherwise Mule will poll it again and again.

Comment: In the case above, i can use the file:outbound-endpoint normally to move the file after i'm done processing it?

Comment: Not sure how you would do that, ie moving a file with an outbound endpoint?

Comment: Forget that, my mistake. I tought that the file outbound endpoint would move the original file (inbound) but it actually saves the payload content in a new file.

Comment: David, can you please help me on this.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657425/mule-how-to-pass-file-from-ftp-to-java-class-in-mule-esb