# How to get handle to original file from file:outbound-endpoint in mule

Tags: mule

In a flow something like below:

```
<flow name="fileFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/inbound/ftp/sbc" pollingFrequency="30000" fileAge="30000" moveToDirectory="/inbound/ftp/sbc/archive">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Entering #[flow.name] flow" level="INFO"/>
    <component class="com.abc.RequestFile"/>
    <logger message="Payload after transformation is: #[payload] flow" level="INFO"/>
     <vm:outbound-endpoint path="merge" />  
    <logger message="Exiting #[flow.name] flow" level="INFO"/>
</flow>
```

I get `InputStream` from `file:inbound-endpoint` which is passed to `RequestFile` component. This component is required to return a list of files of which one of this is the original one read and passed. I am seeking a solution other than manual copying InputStream to File in java component.

Comment: Do you need the `InputStream` at all?

Comment: No, I just need original file and from the location of originalFile, I intend to read another file using MuleClient (and convert that to File) and return both files as List

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397775/387927 you can get the `java.io.File` object instead of its content with this setting:

```
<file:connector name="fileConnector" streaming="false" autoDelete="false">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.file.FileMuleMessageFactory" />
</file:connector>
```

Note that it is up to you to move / delete the file either before you start or once you've done processing it, otherwise Mule will poll it again and again.

Comment: aah... that makes it a not so easy choice :) Thank you

Comment: David, I need ur help on following question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657425/mule-how-to-pass-file-from-ftp-to-java-class-in-mule-esb --

Please respond back..