# Mule: How to pass File from FTP to Java class in Mule ESB?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

In Mule, I am downloading files from FTP server. I want to pass all the files in this directory to my java class which should be performing actions after Download_ZIP_File in my flow. I need to perform actions like reading text files and unzip the zipped files using Java.

There should be a Java class in my flow, for which a function call should be raised when download is complete.. Object of this class must know all the information about downloaded files.

Can someone please help on this.? Here is my current flow;

[image]

My XML for this flow is like this;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp"
        xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
        ... >
    <file:endpoint name="Download_File_KBB" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="E:\csv\output"/>
    <file:connector name="Global_File_Connector" autoDelete="false" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="ftp_kbb_download_fileFlow1" doc:name="ftp_kbb_download_fileFlow1">
       <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="${ftp.host}" port="${ftp.port}" path="${ftp.pathInbound}" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="KBB_FTP">
       </ftp:inbound-endpoint>
       <logger message="KBBUsedVehiclesNoSpecTabFormat-#[server.dateTime.year]-W#[server.dateTime.weekOfYear]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
       <file:outbound-endpoint path="${file.inboundEndpoint}" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Donwload_ZIP_FILE" connector-ref="Global_File_Connector"/>
    </flow>
  </mule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a class that implements `org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable` then configure it with a `component` element in your config.

Then, you will have full access to the `MuleEventContext` in the `onCall` method of this `Callable` class.

Comment: Thanks David, I am almost there.. Please tell me how can I pass properties from mule-app.properties to the message of MuleEventContext of this java component. The problem is that I am getting endpoints of FTP server in MuleEventContext and file names as well. But I am not getting my file.inboundEndpoint location where the file on my local machine is saved. I need to know this property to process the downloaded file...

Comment: Use Spring to inject these properties in your component.

Comment: I got is working.. referred to Object Factories at http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Java+Components ... We need to simply create Setter Function in the sample class which implements Callable

Comment: David, Can you please answer on this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704818/how-to-use-value-of-server-datetime-weekofyear-in-mule-app-properties-or-conf